# How to automate google 2-factor authentication using Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, browser-automation, puppeteer

(I want to automate a report download from Adwords. This report is not part of their API. So I thought of downloading it using browser automation.
I'm using Puppeteer for browser automation.

But the problem is my account is 2-factor authentication enabled (I can't disable is due to security policy). And hence each time i will have to enter the OTP or backup codes. 
I tried adding the backup codes to an array and take one from it each time when required. But Google provides only 10 code at a time and hence it wont be fully automated.

Is any way I can fully automate the entire workflow?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it's still required, But as an alternative solution you can use python with selenium and pyotp(2 factor authentication ). Here I posted sample login + 2 factor auth. which can able to modify for the api as well.

```
import pyotp
from pyotp import TOTP
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver_v80.exe') 
driver.get("https://www.example.com/")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

login_username = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
login_username.clear()
login_username.send_keys(username)

login_passoword = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
login_passoword.clear()
login_passoword.send_keys(password)

driver.find_element_by_name("login").click()

# wait for the 2FA field to display
authField = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='token']")))

# get the token from google authenticate
ga_secret = "4ythgotj3d784rjy6jw94o2xczpjgnta"   #your GA 32 character hash
totp = TOTP(ga_secret)
token = totp.now()
print(token)

# enter the token in the UI
authField.send_keys(token)
# click on the button to complete 2FA
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='token_login']").click()

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The workflow cannot be shared just like that in an answer. Here are some alternative resources that will help you achieve the desired result.

You are looking for the [Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/reporting) provided by google developers, it will let you download the reports as you wish. There is a [rate limit](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/ratesheet) set for this api. You will also need to read more about the [OAuth refresh token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer).

[image]

Otherwise, If you want to automate the entire workflow using Puppeteer. I'd suggest automating the **generation of OTP/Backup codes** as part of workflow. That way you can have unlimited OTP codes available for you. Though it feels using their API would be the best choice.

If you have any related code, add them in your question and I'll be happy to update my answer accordingly.

Comment: The report I want is not available via api

Comment: Then please add more details about the report etc. It's not easy to solve something without more data.

Comment: So I need the Change History report download to be automated. But as far as I know it is not part of the API as of now.  Any idea how to make it happen?